# Small indentation in rechargeable battery

Tags: batteries, usb-device, damage

I bought a small lamp and opened it up. I used a knife to carefully separate the top from the bottom shell and I am pretty sure I didn't insert it that much to create the two points on the left, and the scratch in the middle of the battery.

But wether I did or didn't: Is this thing still safe to use? I mean it works, but I don't want it to explode in my face and I don't have any idea what these batteries can take and if that's dangerous or not. It's a rather small battery and it's charged via micro-USB, as you can see.

[image: Rechargeable battery].

Comment: Li-on batteries ... Always watch, especially if they "swell". The best is to use rigid "encapsulated" batteries.

Comment: The first question is, is the plastic bag punctured or not? If punctured, then battery is dangerous. If not, it may be, but it is hard to qualify if that dent is too much or not.

Comment: I have marred lipos like this in the past and they haven’t caught fire.

Comment: it may be an imprint made by the plastic cover

Comment: Sorry, somehow I can't reply to individual coments … About choice: I didn't had a choice, but if it were up to me I would choose something solid and reachargeable as well.

Comment: About punctured: I don't know, it works though. The battery is not swolen. How would I know if it is punctured? What would happen if it were? This could ignite even if the device is not charging and turned off?

Comment: >  I have marred lipos like this in the past and they haven’t caught fire.

Ah good to hear! I can live with the idea that it is from the plastic cover and not my fault ;P